# How to create a loop function that will create data frames by using different sql queries

Tags: r, function, loops

I try to create a loop that will create data frames by using different sql queries that have the same name exept the day number.For example here is the name for query that is for day 1 :`SF_2013_Day1_BaseLine` and this is for day 6:    `SF_2013_Day6_BaseLine`. I wrote this code (below) but I got an error : `Error: unexpected ',' in "for(i in 3,"` .So any Idea how can i get this code to work ?
Thank you

```
for (i in 1,3,6,10,14,21,30) {
    SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day[i]_BaseLine<-sqlQuery(DB,"select * from [SF_2013_Day[i]_BaseLine]");
    dim(SF_Day[i]_BaseLine)}
```

## After a change based on @Pgibas edvice to this code :

```
 for (i in c(1,3,6,10,14,21,30)) {
        SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day[i]_BaseLine<-sqlQuery(DB,"select * from [SF_2013_Day[i]_BaseLine]");
        dim(SF_Day[i]_BaseLine)}
```

I got this error: `Error: unexpected input in "for(i in c(3,6)){glm_d[i]_"` . What can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: Just to solve you problem: `for (i in c(1,3,6,10,14,21,30)) { ... }`

Comment: thanks @Pgibas, but now i get another error: Error: unexpected input in "for(i in c(3,6)){glm_d[i]_"  . I didn't wrote functions like this until now so I don't know how check what is wrong.

Comment: Edit your question, can't understand what you wrote in comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resolve `i` within the names first:

```
for (i in c(1,3,6,10,14,21,30)) {
  set <- sqlQuery(DB, paste0("select * from [SF_2013_Day[", i, "]_BaseLine]"))
  eval(parse(text = paste0("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day", i, "_BaseLine <- set"))
  dim(set)
}
```